# how to make an element stretch the entire width of its parent

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

in my Windows Phone application I have  such structure:

```
  <Grid Width="460" Height="77" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Background="#FFD20000" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel Width="Auto"   Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton_A" Content="Info" Width="150" Style="{StaticResource ToggleA}" Click="ToggleButton_A_Click"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
```

In my case I have a button in the center of conteiner. But I need to make it fill all place of it's parent conteiner, how can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the stackpanel, and the ToggleButton will fill all the grid. Everything is about using the right container for the right task.

Comment: but I use the stackpanel, because I will have spme more element( some ToggleButtons)

Comment: Then use instead of a Stackpanel another Grid